# Safari Mobile (Ipad 4) Animation (rotate) not working

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad, safari

Hey I do have the following code :

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

and the call :

```
-webkit-animation: rotate 1000ms infinite linear;
```

Unfortunately, my spinner is still not rotating on Ipad/Iphone

Any idea why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The came from the fact that I needed :

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

It is now fixed